# How to divide/split formatter settings for Groovy and Java in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, formatter

Eclipse use the same Code formatter for Groovy and Java.
But I need different space/tabs rules for Java and for Groovy (in Java tab=4spaces, in Groovy tab=2spaces, etc.)

Maybe someone knows trick for divide formatters for java and groovy in eclipse? some plugin? some special settings?..

[image: formatter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that your Java code and groovy code in the same project should be formatted differently?  If so, that's not supported since all the use cases we considered had Groovy code inheriting the formatting preferences of Java.

If, however, your Java and Groovy code are in separate projects, you can use project specific settings for the different projects.

Comment: Ok, now clear. But in my company use different code convention for java and groovy. I think main reason for that - groovy closer to script languages then to static..
and yes - we use groovy and java on the same project.. it happened :)